# What would the style of wanted posters be in 1500's

Tags: spain

In Spain, what would be the style of wanted poster (for pirates)?

Would it be like the Wild West type of a more modern poster.

Comment: There wouldn't have been wanted posters on Pirates. None of the people who would see the poster would be in a position to do anything about it. A government might pass messages to it's navy, along the lines of "Mad Jack is causing too much damage to shipping, send a squadron and route him out". Even sailors would have no use for a bounty poster. If the pirate attacked their ship, they'll know soon enough who it is.

Comment: 'Wanted' notices in ports could serve a purpose of tracking pirate's movements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't believe there were any wanted posters in Spain in the 1500's.  If you have evidence, please document your preliminary research in your question.

The first record I can find of a wanted poster in Europe was [1881](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanted_poster); although the comments suggest that wanted posters were common in the US at that time.  True West Magazine [suggests](http://www.truewestmagazine.com/jcontent/history/history/ask-the-marshall/5741-when-were-photos-first-put-on-wanted-posters) (non-conclusive) that they date from the last half of the 19th century.

Wikipedia on [Calico Jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calico_Jack) cites an illustration in a 1722 book.  If a wanted poster existed, I suspect they would have used that in preference to a woodcut.

According to the [history of posters](http://gallery.sjsu.edu/paris/mass_produced_art/PostersOpening.htm), "The first posters were created in the mid 19th century in France as advertisements for new products."  Which suggests that posters and wanted posters both emerged well after the 1500's

Comment: I wonder what definition they're using for "poster."  As far back as ancient Greece and Rome, people would post public letters on the doors of the Senate house or other buildings.  A large sheet of paper (or parchment or papyrus, etc) on a wall with a message for the public matches my definition of a "poster."

Comment: @Nerrolken Which examples from Greece and Rome do you have in mind?

Comment: Pamphlets were common in Europe during the 18th century. A famous one is, for instance, "Aan het volk van Nederland", which spread in 1781 throughout all major Dutch cities. Or this one, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pamphlet#mediaviewer/File:Pamphlet_dutch_tulipomania_1637.jpg, dating from 1637.

Answer (score 4):

They looked like this:

[image]

In all seriousness, though, wanted notices were more a product of the 18th century (1700s) when printing became cheaper, although such notices also appeared in latter part of the 17th century. In the 1500s paper and printed matter was expensive and most people could not read.

There were definitely bounties offered, for example, it is rumored that Phillip put a bounty on Francis Drake's head, but it is hard to find documentation of such offers before 1650.